# Erro ao aceder pelo login em servidor alojado num IIS local

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, webforms

Quando testo na minha maquina o login funciona perfeitamente, quando partilho pela rede retorna me o seguinte erro:

> A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while
>   establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or
>   was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that
>   SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL
>   Network Interfaces, error: 50 - Local Database Runtime error occurred.
>   Cannot create an automatic instance. See the Windows Application event
>   log for error details.

estou a utilizar a versão IIS 8.5, a minha aplicação é do tipo WebForm Asp.Net,
O login que utilizo é o que já é proveniente da aplicação.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O problema pode ser que você está usando um banco de dados local durante o desenvolvimento, mas esse banco de dados não existe na máquina de destino, ou seja, a máquina onde você está hospedando sua aplicação.

**Soluções possíveis:**

- Altere a string de conexão do banco de dados, para um banco de dados que seja acessível da máquina de destino.
- Ou então você pode criar um banco de dados diretamente na máquina de destino, caso isso seja possível.